# Number density equation in BCS Theory

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, tight-binding

In [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s100510050221) paper, The author has given two-equation

$$\frac{1}{U}=\sum_k \frac{1}{E(k)}\tanh\left(\frac{\beta E(k)}{2}\right)$$

and $$2\rho-1=-\sum_k \frac{\epsilon(k)}{E(k)}\tanh\left(\frac{\beta E(k)}{2}\right)$$

with $E(k)=\sqrt{\epsilon(k)^2+\Delta^2}$ and $\epsilon(k)=-2t\cos (k)-\mu$ (considering one dimensional case). Here $\rho$ is the density of electrons per site and per spin, i.e.
$\rho = 1 $ corresponds to the fully occupied lattice with 2 electrons of opposite spin at each site.

---

The first equation is the gap equation. But I don't understand how to go about deriving the second equation. Can someone give any hint?

---

Edit-

With the help of Meng Cheng, I found the following -
Using
$$a_{p\uparrow}=u_p\gamma_{p\uparrow}+v_p\gamma^\dagger_{-p\uparrow} \\
a^\dagger_{p\uparrow} = u_p \gamma^\dagger_{p\uparrow}+v_p\gamma_{-p\downarrow}$$
We can find the average number of particles using-
$$N_p=2\langle c^\dagger_{p\uparrow}c_{p\uparrow}\rangle =2\langle (u_p \gamma^\dagger_{p\uparrow}+v_p\gamma_{-p\downarrow})(u_p\gamma_{p\uparrow}+v_p\gamma^\dagger_{-p\uparrow})\rangle  \\
= 2|u_p|^2 \ \langle \gamma^\dagger_{p\uparrow} \gamma_{p\uparrow }  \rangle  +|2v_p|^2\ \langle \gamma_{-p\downarrow}\gamma_{-p\downarrow}^\dagger\rangle \\
= -\frac{\epsilon(p)}{E(p)}\tanh\left(\frac{\beta E(p)}{2}\right)+1$$
I put the expectation values of $\gamma^\dagger_{p\uparrow}\gamma^\dagger_{-p\downarrow}$ and $\gamma_{-p\downarrow}\gamma_{p\uparrow}$, considering the ground state.

Total number of particles given by
$$N= \sum_p N_p = -\sum_p\frac{\epsilon(p)}{E(p)}\tanh\left(\frac{\beta E(p)}{2}\right)+\sum_p1$$

I don't how to reform it to given form.

Comment: You can compute the average of electron number in the BCS mean field, which should give you the second equation.

Comment: The effective Hamiltonian given by $H= \sum_k E(k) (\gamma^\dagger_{k\uparrow} \gamma_{k\uparrow }+ \gamma^\dagger_{k\downarrow}\gamma_{p\downarrow})$ so do I have have to find $N=\langle \gamma^\dagger_{k\sigma}\gamma_{k\sigma}\rangle $?

Comment: Well $\gamma_{k\sigma}$ are the Bogoliubov quasiparticles. You want to find $N=\sum_{k,\sigma} \langle c_{k\sigma}^\dagger c_{k\sigma}\rangle$, where $c$'s are electron operators. They can be related to $\gamma$'s by the Bogoliubov transformation.

Comment: @MengCheng Can you see the edit?

Comment: Yes. If $\rho=1$ means 2 electrons per site, then $N/N_s=2\rho$, where $N_s$ is the number of sites. Then you more or less have it (note that the number of lattice momenta in the first Brillouin zone is the same as the number of sites), except that the $\sum_p (\cdots)$ should have a $1/N_s$ in front.

Comment: @MengCheng Yeah! That's right. There hadn't mentioned a factor of $1/N_s$ in front of the right-hand side but it should be there. Thanks :)